# unordered map with custom hash function (_bstr_t) works only with default constructor (duplicate keys)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, unordered-map

I have an unordered map with a _bstr_t key type. So, as this key type is not supported by hash function by default, then I defined the functor:

```
struct KeyHash {
    size_t operator()(const _bstr_t& key) const {
        return hash<LPCTSTR>()(key);
    }
};
```

Next i defined typedef:

```
typedef unordered_map<_bstr_t, RecentInfo*, KeyHash> RecentInfoMap;
```

And there problem appears: if I instantiate RecentInfoMap with default constructor

```
RecentMapInfo rim;
```

then all working fine. But if I want to instantiate RecentInfoMap with initial buckets count

```
RecentInfoMap rim(100);
```

Then map don't working. I can't get values by it's keys. Also if i invoke rim.rehash(100) before map usage then also don't working.

Please explain what am I doing wrong.

UPDATED: some code examples:

```
unordered_map<bstr_t, int, KeyHash> map;
_bstr_t t1("ORCL");
_bstr_t t2("ORCL");
map[t1] = 777;
map[t2] = 555;
fout << map[t1] << endl;
fout << map[t2] << endl;
```

There are all OK: map[t1] and map[t2] references to one value 555.
But if map defined as

```
 unordered_map<bstr_t, int, KeyHash> map(100);
```

Then there are errors: map contains duplicate keys and map[t1] references to 777 and map[t2] references to 555.

This statement (with rehash invoking) also give duplicate keys:

```
unordered_map<bstr_t, int, KeyHash> map;
map.rehash(100);
```

Comment: Whats the actual errors you get?

Comment: With no-default constructor map don't return values by it's keys. As if the key-value pair is not in the map.

Comment: post some code exhibiting the problem with actual output vs. expected output

Comment: I added some code examples in the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Just written my own custom hash function which can work with char* (wchar_t*) pointers. Also added equality functor. Works fine for me. Hope it will be useful to somebody.

```
struct KeyHash {
    size_t operator()(const _bstr_t& key) const {
        LPCTSTR str = key;
        LPCTSTR end = str + _tcslen(str);
        size_t hash = 2166136261U;
        while (str != end) {
            hash = 16777619U * hash ^ static_cast<size_t>(*str++);
        }
        return hash;
    }
};


struct KeyEquals {
    bool operator()(const _bstr_t& x, const _bstr_t& y) const {
        return _tcscmp(x, y) == 0;
    }
};


typedef unordered_map<_bstr_t, RecentInfo*, KeyHash, KeyEquals> RecentInfoMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to double check what `KeyHash()(t1)` and `KeyHash()(t2)` return.

It could be that you are very (un)lucky that it works at all in the first case. Although this is kind of a shot in the dark as I don't know much about these windows data types.

Comment: I checked few minutes ago, you're right - KeyHash return different hash results for t1 and t2. And I still do not know why.

Comment: @EldarAgalarov Because VS2010 does not provide a special `char*` hash, but only the Standard `hash<T*>` partial specialization. It then internally uses an integer hash of the pointer value (and does not hash the string itself) -- which complies with the Standard.